# Elements position changing as you scroll to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/181zpvf2/

I am having some issues getting the `<aside>` element to stick to the bottom of the `#main` container when the user scrolls past it.

I have the `<aside>` element stick to the top once the user starts to scroll past it using the elements `offset.top` property, but since there is not a `offset.bottom` property, I am running into some issues figuring out how to get the math to work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `offset().bottom` but there's `offset().top` and `height()`. With that you get `offset().bottom`.

```
var offsetTop = $("aside").offset().top;
var offsetBottom = $("aside").offset().top + $("aside").height();
```

Now, with this you can do your math. Ask if you get stuck :-)

Comment: Those damn ninja downvoters. Why? An explanation will help to improve :-/

Answer (score 0):

Use `offset.top + window.innerHeight`. This adds the window height to the offset of the screen so you get the position of the bottom of the screen.

```
var PositionFromTop = offset.top + window.innerHeight;
document.getElementById('asideElement').style.marginTop = PositionFromTop;
```